# Looping through dictionary and updating in python List Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following two lists
`states = ('ab',['rose','cose'])`
`flowers = {'rose':0,'cose:0','mose:0'}`

Now need the `flowers` dictionary to be changed to
`flowers = {'rose':1,'cose:1','mose:0'}`
after I loop th `states`

I tried this but some syntax seems to be a problem!

`[flowers[i] = 1 for i in states[1] if i in flowers.keys()]`

Help is really appreciated! I am not able to understand, I kept the expression first and the conditional in the last! :/

Comment: I hope your data structure makes sense in a wider context, because it doesn't at all from just what you've shown. There's no need for `flowers` to be a `list`, if you only ever care about the single `dict` value it contains. If you don't need the list, just reference the `dict` directly!

Comment: Yes, thats my mistake I meant for it be a single `dict` not a `list`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using list comprehension for this problem, as you are modifying your existing list not making a new one.

```
for i in states[1]:
    flowers[0][i] += 1
flowers
>>>[{'rose':1,'cose':1,'mose':0}]
```

If you insist on list comprehension:

```
new_flowers = [{i:states[1].count(i) for i in flowers[0]}]
new_flowers
>>>[{'rose': 1, 'cose': 1, 'mose': 0}]
```

Note this doesn't modify your original dict of flowers but instead makes a new one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections
counter = collections.Counter(states[-1])
new_flowers = [{a:counter.get(a, b) for a, b in i.items()} for i in flowers]
```

Output:

```
[{'rose': 1, 'cose': 1, 'mose': 0}]
```